# mvn install is not working in eclipse but works fine from command line

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am unable to build a project through eclipse but it works fine when I run mvn clean install. I am getting the following issue.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project abc-xxx: Execution default-
install of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install 
failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its 
dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4 -> 
org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5: Failed to read artifact descriptor 
for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5: Could not transfer artifact 
org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:pom:3.0.5 from/to anonymous 
(https://nexus.xxx.xxx.xxx/nexus/content/groups/xxx):     
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid  certification path to requested target
```

Comment: What java version are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure the **JDK** you are using in the command line is the same that you are using in your *IDE*.

In the command line type:

```
java -version
```

Then inside eclipse:

```
 windows -> preferences -> Installed JREs
```

---

The same goes for **maven**:

In the command line type:

```
mvn -version
```

In eclipse:

```
 windows -> preferences -> Maven -> User settings
 windows -> preferences -> Maven -> Installations
```

Comment: Maven version was different on eclipse which I set up and now working. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem, now it works great. :D